# Creating new rows in a dataframe using column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to format a messy dataframe in R by creating new rows from column values. A snip of the data looks like this.

```
id  producer  pcountry  collaborator  ccountry   val
1    J&J       USA        Pfizer       USA       25

2    Biodiem   AUS        PhaseBio     USA       65
                          GeneScience  China     

3    Shire     Ireland       N/A        N/A      54

4    Sanofi    France        N/A        N/A      64
```

Essentially, I want to use the values in the last two columns to create new rows in the dataframe. So far, I have this code, using the `splitstackshape` package.

```
df2 <- cSplit(df, 4, "\r", "long")
```

This does the job for the entries that have more than one value in the collaborator column (like row 2 above). Using my code gives me this: `

```
id  producer  pcountry  collaborator  ccountry   val
1    J&J       USA        Pfizer       USA       25

2    Biodiem   AUS        PhaseBio     USA       65
                                       China     

3    Biodiem   AUS        Genescience  USA       65
                                       China

4    Shire     Ireland       N/A        N/A      54

5    Sanofi    France        N/A        N/A      64
```

However, there are more things that I want to do with the data that I am struggling with. I want the values of the collaborator column to match the values of the ccountry column, so row 3 here would have the value `China` in the `ccountry` column, while row 2 would have `USA`. I tried adding both columns in the code, like so `df2 <- cSplit(df, c(4,5), "\r", "long")`, but that only makes a big mess.

Finally, because the code only makes new entries using the new line separator, it ignores the ones that only have 1 value (like row 1), because they don't have new lines. I want those to be included as well.

Is there any way to change this code to do these 2 additional steps, or would I have to write a function for that?

EDIT: This is the data snippet

```
     id producer pcountry collaborator              ccountry         val
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                     <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 J&J      USA      Pfizer                    USA               25
2     2 Biodiem  AUS      "PhaseBio\r\nGenescience" "USA\r\nChina"    65
3     3 Shire    Ireland  NA                        NA                54
4     4 Sanofi   France   NA                        NA                64
```

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), producer = c("J&J", "Biodiem", 
"Shire", "Sanofi"), pcountry = c("USA", "AUS", "Ireland", "France"
), collaborator = c("Pfizer", "PhaseBio\r\nGenescience", NA, 
NA), ccountry = c("USA", "USA\r\nChina", NA, NA), val = c(25, 
65, 54, 64)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and this is the expected result

```
     id producer pcountry collaborator ccountry   val
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>        <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 J&J      USA      NA           NA          25
2     2 J&J      USA      Pfizer       USA         25
3     3 Biodiem  AUS      NA           NA          65
4     4 Biodiem  AUS      PhaseBio     USA         65
5     5 Biodiem  AUS      Genescience  China       65
6     6 Shire    Ireland  NA           NA          54
7     7 Sanofi   France   NA           NA          64
```

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), producer = c("J&J", 
"J&J", "Biodiem", "Biodiem", "Biodiem", "Shire"), pcountry = c("USA", 
"USA", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "Ireland"), collaborator = c(NA, 
"Pfizer", NA, "PhaseBio", "Genescience", NA), ccountry = c(NA, 
"USA", NA, "USA", "China", NA), val = c(25, 25, 65, 65, 65, 54
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Can you provide the data snip as a `dput` output? Will make it easier to recreate the data.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: Thanks, but instead of posting your data in a text form like you did, do `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and post the results

Comment: I added that to my OP

Comment: Looking at your expected output - do you WANT to have rows with NA like rows 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's super easy with `tidyr`:

```
require(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, collaborator,ccountry, sep="\r\n")

# A tibble: 5 x 6
     id producer pcountry collaborator ccountry   val
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>        <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 J&J      USA      Pfizer       USA         25
2     2 Biodiem  AUS      PhaseBio     USA         65
3     2 Biodiem  AUS      Genescience  China       65
4     3 Shire    Ireland  NA           NA          54
5     4 Sanofi   France   NA           NA          64
```

If you want all those extra rows with NAs for collaborator and ccountry, you can do this:

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(collaborator=ifelse(is.na(collaborator), NA, paste0("\r\n",collaborator)), 
    ccountry=ifelse(is.na(ccountry), NA, paste0("\r\n",ccountry))) %>% # Create extra rows before non NA rows
  separate_rows(collaborator,ccountry, sep="\r\n") %>% 
  mutate(collaborator=ifelse(collaborator=="",NA,collaborator), 
    ccountry=ifelse(ccountry=="", NA, ccountry)) # change empty strings to NAs
# A tibble: 7 x 6
     id producer pcountry collaborator ccountry   val
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>        <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 J&J      USA      NA           NA          25
2     1 J&J      USA      Pfizer       USA         25
3     2 Biodiem  AUS      NA           NA          65
4     2 Biodiem  AUS      PhaseBio     USA         65
5     2 Biodiem  AUS      Genescience  China       65
6     3 Shire    Ireland  NA           NA          54
7     4 Sanofi   France   NA           NA          64
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great with the example. Only trouble is, some of the names in "collaborator" in my full data file have spaces between them (i.e. "Smith & Nephew"). I guess that the code thinks that those are 3 entries, and it throws up an error "Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.". Any idea how to get around that ?

Comment: Yes, you can add `sep="\r\n"` as an argument to the `separate_rows` call (updated code in my answer). This should deal with cases like that.

Comment: It does, however it then ignores the single ones, so in my original post it catches row 2, but not row 1 because it doesn't have a new line. Anyway, the single ones are not that many in my data so I could do them manually, but I'm just wondering what the code would like then.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to do it with a regular expression, thanks again for the help.

Comment: That's strange - it worked for me (the second option in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Consider a base R approach using `strsplit` inside a `by` grouping process:

```
# BUILD LIST OF SUBSET DFs WITH EXPANDED ROWS
df_list <- by(df, df[c("id", "producer", "pcountry", "val")], function(sub)
    data.frame(id = sub$id[1],
               producer = sub$producer[1],
               pcountry = sub$pcountry[1],
               collaborator = c(unlist(strsplit(as.character(sub$collaborator), "\r\n")[1]), NA),
               ccountry = c(unlist(strsplit(as.character(sub$ccountry), "\r\n")[1]), NA),
               val = sub$val[1])
)

# APPEND SUBSETS
final_df <- unique(do.call(rbind, df_list))

# RE-ORDER ROWS AND RESET ROW NAMES
final_df <- with(final_df, final_df[order(id, producer, pcountry, val),])
row.names(final_df) <- NULL

final_df
#   id producer pcountry collaborator ccountry val
# 1  1      J&J      USA       Pfizer      USA  25
# 2  1      J&J      USA         <NA>     <NA>  25
# 3  2  Biodiem      AUS     PhaseBio      USA  65
# 4  2  Biodiem      AUS  Genescience    China  65
# 5  2  Biodiem      AUS         <NA>     <NA>  65
# 6  3    Shire  Ireland         <NA>     <NA>  54
# 7  4   Sanofi   France         <NA>     <NA>  64
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/IITX35749)